# Copy files from remote server over ssh inside a loop

Tags: loops, ssh, cat

I'm trying to download some files over ssh.
Files are in folders (folder1 folder2 folder3), so I decided to loop.

The following doesn't work:

ssh user@remotehost 'for i in 1 2 3; for filename in /folder$i/*.log; do cat /$filename > /localdrive; done; done;'

Any hint?
Thanks!

Comment: Not going to work. the `/localdrive` is going to be `remotehost:/localdrive`. The ENTIRE command inside the `'` goes over to the remote host.You'd need to do something more like `for (...) do scp user@remotehost:remotefile localfile` instead.

Comment: scp intends "localfile" on the remote host too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
rsync -e ssh --include '*.log' --exclude '*' username@yourserver:/folder[1-3]/ /'yourlocaldirectory'
```

Rysnc uses scp internally.

OR for AIX system(as yours):
Use:

```
scp remote:"/folser[1-3]/*.txt" local:/'yourlocaldirectory'
```

Hope it resolves your issue!

Comment: I'm on AIX with no rsync :(

Comment: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/download.html    ..try downloading aix rsync utility. Is scp installed on your machine?